# VueDX warning: component is inferred as global component

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuetify.js, vuedx

So I added an extension of VueDX and now I am having a lot of warnings.

`The component 'v-row' is inferred as global component. It may not be available at runtime.VueDX(59002)`
And the same way with `v-col` or `v-main` or `v-card` basically any Vuetify component gives me warnings.
How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/znck/vue-developer-experience/issues/197#issuecomment-778580927), you should be able to configure global components in a `vueconfig.json` configuration file. Create this file in the root directory:

*vueconfig.json*

```json
{
  "globalComponents": [
    "vuetify"
  ]
}
```

---

There's a note about attribute completion in that thread from the project creator:

> Attribute completion depends on type definitions but it will support web types soon.